# How does webapi project accepts value from client and pass it to .html?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-webapi

The server side is a .NetCore WebAPI project (not MVC), it stores a file called

> greeting.html

```
...
<td class="class1">Hi</td>
...
```

Previously the client only wants to open this .html file from server (Assuming `localhost` is the server):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://localhost:5001/greeting/greeting.html"));
```

Now the client wants to pass a string `name` to this .html file then open it:

```
...
<td class="class1">Hi {name}</td>
...
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Parameters are normally at the end of the URI after a question mark : https://localhost:5001/greeting/greeting.html?name=Bob

Comment: @jdweng is right, but worth mentioning- in this approach (passing values in the url query - GET method) all values will be visible to the user and to the network (not encrypted)

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with web development. After the parameters are passed to server side, must I use MVC and replace .html with .cshtml to achieve this (name databinding)?

Comment: not at all, it depends what you want to do with them. you can use javascript to get them and/or to send them elsewhere

Comment: So the aim is just to show name as per the value passed from client. `<td class="class1"Hi {name}</td>` is the pseudocode @Yair Maron

Comment: Well, in html you cannot just put some code inside to be generated. using JS you can write a script to run on load, and inside you can get the url query parameters like this: URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('name'); and then you can update the required element in the document. But this is more of a JS related question, unrelated to c# at all

Comment: I added a full answer for you, let me know if it does what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your file url the required parameters, like this:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://localhost:5001/greeting/greeting.html?name=Simon&age=25"));
```

Then you can fetch them in the html file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    Hello <Label id="name" />
    
    <script>
        urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        nameParam = urlParams.get('name');
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = nameParam;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I am looking for!